# for loop not looping Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem. I am writing a bot in Selenium. I'm working with 3 arrays but for loop not working. All elements of the array are written to an input. You can see the codes below.
How can I fix? 
Best regards.

bot.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import list

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("")
time.sleep(4)
sayi=1
for posta, isim, kadi in zip(instagramList.email,instagramList.fullName,instagramList.userName):
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='emailOrPhone']").send_keys(posta)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='fullName']").send_keys(isim)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']").send_keys(kadi)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']").send_keys("+1gP5xc!")
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Sign').click()
print(str(sayi)+". "+ "Kayit olustu.")
sayi = sayi+1
```

list.py

```
email=["abidinkandemir@evtsoft.com", "asd@asd.com", "sdsd@asd.com"],
fullName=["abidin kandemir","asd asd", "asdd asd"],
userName=["abidinkandemir102","asdas", "asdd"]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "not working" mean? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you confirm whether the code that follows the `for` statement line is indented or not? The code that should be in the loop will need to be indented below the `for` statement line.

Comment: The easiest way to show code here is to paste it into your question, then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to indent the whole block by four spaces.

Comment: You seem to be using `list` and `instagramList` interchangeably. Also, don't name a module `list`, as it conflicts with the name for the built-in `list` type.

Answer (score 1):

1. For example, you have renamed the file with lists to "instagramList.py".
2. In "bot.py" file you need to import that file like: `import instagramList`.

After these steps, your script should work one iteration (If you are correctly intended your code):

bot.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import instagramList


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("your_url")
time.sleep(4)
sayi = 1

for posta, isim, kadi in zip(instagramList.email, instagramList.fullName, instagramList.userName):

    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='emailOrPhone']").send_keys(posta)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='fullName']").send_keys(isim)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']").send_keys(kadi)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']").send_keys("+1gP5xc!")
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Sign").click()
    print(str(sayi) + ". Kayit olustu.")
    sayi = sayi + 1
```

instagramList.py

```
email = ["abidinkandemir@evtsoft.com", "asd@asd.com", "sdsd@asd.com"],
fullName = ["abidin kandemir","asd asd", "asdd asd"],
userName = ["abidinkandemir102","asdas", "asdd"]
```

PS: Even after this your code will not work as you expected. Why? You need after each login does "logout"-action and open the Login page with `browser.get("your_url")`.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Good answer to a bad question... :)